# Creating a matrix with certain conditions

Tags: numpy, pytorch

I am trying to create a matrix using PyTorch of size 32x10x1.
The conditions that I need to fulfill are that

```
torch.mean(a, dim=0) # size is 10x1 and should be almost 0
torch.mean(a, dim=1) # size is 32x1 and should be almost 0
```

This is a noise matrix for GANs and I am trying to sample it from Normal Distribution. I tried using torch.MultiVariateNormal() but it didnt give me matrix of that shape

Is there any other function or something in numpy or scikit to get this kind of matrix

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.random.normal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html)

```
import numpy.random as npr

mean = 0
std_dev = 0.1
size = (32, 10, 1)

mat = npr.normal(loc=mean, scale=std_dev, size=size)
```

and set the mean and standard deviation as desired to keep the values close to 0.

Here you can see the effect of changing the mean and standard deviation on the graph
[image]
By Inductiveload - self-made, Mathematica, Inkscape, Public Domain, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=3817954

Comment: Does this ensure the above conditions that I had specified? As the mean of entire 32x10x1 will be close to 0

Comment: @sidewala The mean of the values will definitely be zero.  You can tweak the standard deviation to any value that you would like to get the values closer and closer to zero.  The only tradeoff is your values will start to pile on top of each other if you get too close.  Might be something you have to experiment with in your individual case.

Comment: @sidewala Did this end up working for you?  We can try a few other avenues if it didn't.

Comment: No not really, but instead i tried a different method which kind of worked that way but not exactly

Comment: @sidewala Definitely add yours as an answer in case it could help someone in the future